# Is there a way to get the coordinates of xticklabel in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

this code gives a matplotlib figure

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

and then, this code gives the info about a xticklabel

```
a = list(ax.get_xticklabels())[3]
print(a)
```

that is

```
Text(0.6, 0, '0.6')
```

which is a [matplotlib.text.Text](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text).

`a.get_text()` gives the text value of this object.

```
'0.6'
```

which is a single string.

I went through the [matplotlib.text.Text](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) doc, and didn't find a way to get the coordinates of this xticklabel, (0.6, 0) in this case.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you show output of `a.get_text()` ? it could be a tuple, a list or a variable to which the type can be modified

Comment: @lostCode updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_position()`:

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
text=plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'hola', fontsize=12)
print(text)
print(text.get_position())
```

The text:

```
Text(0.5, 0.5, 'hola')
```

Output (tuple):

```
 (0.5, 0.5)
```

`a.get_position()` should work for you!

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/text.html#Text.get_position